# Why does my Dell 1130n printer not install?

Tags: 12.04, printing

I have a fully updated Ubuntu 12.04 and my Dell laser class 1130n printer won't install via a USB port.  Does anyone have any ideas? It says that I have the wrong driver and it only prints an error page.

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot that I could use the 'generic' driver, it ended up working.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu does not include a driver for your printer.

A google search tells me that Dell's 1130N is actually a rebadged Samsung ML-2580n with customised firmware.
What generic driver did you actually use? Paste the output of this command on a terminal: grep -H '^*NickName:' /etc/cups/ppd/*.ppd

Can you try weather the splix driver for the Samsung ML-2580N, which is included with Ubuntu, works good or better than the generic driver with your printer?
Go to system-config-printer (System -> Administration -> Printing in GNOME classic, Gear icon at the upper right of the screen -> Printers in Unity), right click your Printer and select Properties > click Change... next to the Make and Model field to see the available drivers and change it to Samsung ML-2580N.

Answer (score 0):

We also have 12.04 and tried installing our Dell 1130 on it.  It had worked with 11.10 but we could not do so with 12.04.  To make a long story short we found that someone in another forum found that if you chose the Samsung ML1915 from the manufacturer list instead of the Dell 1130 that it worked just fine.